# Cordova App only shows in split screen view / multiple app view

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

My application  only shows for a second and then vanishes to a white screen. Comes back only if I go to the split screen mode on android 8.1. Works fine on the emulator.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There was a javascript error. Once I got rid of that the app started working fine. The error become visible when I compiled the app for the 'browser' platform instead of the android / ios platform.